# C++ Memory Pooling by Subclassing

Tags: c++, memory-pool

So I was working on a way to memory pool c++ objects easily with minimal modification needed to the class that needs to be pooled.

The memory pool itself is the standard variety you can find anywhere, but I've made this class:

```
  Poolable::Poolable(MemPool& lepool){
     mempool = &lepool;
  }

  Poolable::~Poolable(){
     mempool->returnMemory((char*)this);
  }

  void * Poolable::operator new(size_t size, MemPool& lepool){
     if(!lepool.initialised())
        lepool.initializeBasedOnSize(size);

     return lepool.getMemory(size);

  }

  void Poolable::operator delete(void * p){
     // do absolutely NOTHING
  }
```

usage:

```
  class SomeSubclass : public Poolable { /* boring details here */ };
  MemPool thepool(1000);
  SomeSubclass * woot = new(thepool) SomeSubclass(thepool);
```

I wanted to put the returnMemory call (which basically frees a part of the pool) in the delete operator, but have no idea how to get the actual pool's address from the void* argument.

Instead, I settled by putting it in the destructor. I figure that the constructor mandates that the class was allocated using the pool, which means destruction always implies unallocation will follow.

It's the first working solution, and it's quite convenient to use. However, doing that is probably bad style, and I'm curious if there are better solutions to the problem.

Does anybody know of one?

Comment: Read Modern C++ Design: http://www.amazon.com/Modern-Design-Generic-Programming-Patterns/dp/0201704315

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative would be to make `Poolable::operator new` allocate memory from `thepool` so that you can use usual (non-placement) `new` statements. In your solution the user has to remember that those objects are to be allocated via some special technique, that's showing too much details and putting too much burden onto the user code.

Comment: Ah.. I don't quite understand.. could you elaborate on what you mean with making "operator new" allocate memory from thepool? Do you mean in a different fashion than what it is already doing?

Comment: kamziro: If you don't need more that one pool you can just declare a global variable and make `operator new` use it.

Comment: Oh right -- I do plan to have more than one pool though, but thanks for that idea.

Comment: @kamziro: Even with several pools you can use a global object (pointer) called "current pool" and make `operator new` allocate from that pool. Then you can use a bracket class to switch to the pool you want before doing `new` - this way you can switch to the necessary pool and call a bunch of code and all objects allocated by that code will be allocated in that pool without explicitly specifying it for each allocation separately.